# Creating check box grid using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

The Json structure,

```
[
    {
        "name": "module1",
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "cat1"
            },
            {
                "name": "cat4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "module2",
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "cat3"
            },
            {
                "name": "cat4"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "module3",
        "categories": [
            {
                "name": "cat1"
            },
            {
                "name": "cat2"
            },
            {
                "name": "cat4"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Using this Json structure, I need to display a grid of checkboxes as follows,

[image]

On click of any checkbox, I should be able to alert the corresponding category & module name. If each module has all four categories then I can easily use nested ng-repeat and display the structure (You can check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/IlIK8uJFSm4u9Ud42nDL?p=preview). ). But here the number of categories differs for each module. Could you please suggest a way to implement this functionality?

1. Need to find the number of categories first and display it as the headers in the table
2. Display checkbox exactly at the right place

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to use ui-grid or any type of grid ;)

Comment: @Radu, ui-grid doesnt support firefox<40 or chrome<44. and from my knowledge, no angular grid api supports this kind of behaviour where column count is different in each row of the table :(

Comment: I was thinking of something wirting the code will take some time but as  solution think like this. You can get categories with 2 foreach if you can't aford to have the categories at first. Then you display a line with categories next you will have an ng repeat and  using bootstrap you can divide the screen with cols so you can use ng-hide when no data is present for the cateogiry for that module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have an ng-repeat iterate over the result of a function - in contrast to an array field in the scope - like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="module in getAllModules()">
  <td ng-repeat="cat in getAllCategories()">
     <!-- display checkbox here if required -->
  </td>
</tr>
```

I think it should be clear how to implement the two methods. However, you have to consider the performance overhead involved because the total set of modules and categories is calculated over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

I think lex answer is corrrect. If I understood his solution right,the getAllCategories method is the interesting part. It has to return ALL categories, while getAllModules can still return your modules Array.

```
    <tr ng-repeat="module in modules">
      <td ng-repeat="cat in getAllCategories()">
        <input type="check" ng-if="module.containsCat(cat)">
      </td>
   </tr>
```

with the containsCat method being something like

```
$scope.containsCat = function(module, cat){
    for each(var moduleCat in module.categories ){
        if(moduleCat.name === cat) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```